# Logstash отмена drop

Tags: logstash

Можно ли отменить drop в логсташ если он уже применяется?

Пример:

```
filter {

    if [kubernetes][labels][app] =~ /^dr-.*/ {

    if [level] == "DEBUG" { drop {} } #Дроп во всех индексах
    if [loglevel] == "DEBUG" { drop {} }

}
```

Пример индексов:
dr-1
dr-2
dr-3
dr-4
dr-5
dr-6
dr-10

Нужно чтобы  дропались все debug логи, но иногда требуется что-бы можно было подключить один из индексов и посмотреть логи level=debug.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать и возможно ли это в этом варианте.